# Lag / latency of touches after loading anything

Tags: iphone, touch, touchscreen, lag

Writing a game, and I'm having an issue whereby after loading anything (images / sound effect), the touchscreen suffers a high amount of latency. I tap the screen, and a short time later, that tap is registered. This is barely noticeable on iPhone 4 or iPad, but on anything older (Particularly 2G devices), I'm looking at a good few seconds before touches register!

To be clear, I tap... then take my finger off the screen, and then about 5 seconds later the icon I clicked on registers the tap.

It only seems to happen after loading a large amount of images (Which I do at the start of each level, and when returning to the frontend). Once it 'catches up' it all works fine again.

Is there any way to flush the touches buffer (I assume one must exist!) after a load?

Thanks in advance

Stew

Comment: Is it possible for you to load the images/sound effects in a background thread or asyncronously?

Answer (score 0):

What it sounds like you want to do is "clear you cache".  Loading large images eats up a lot of memory and as we all know, smartphone memory is a valuable commodity ... you just can't get enough of it.  Especially if you are programming in a runtime language that deals with a heap store and garbage collection.  Often times you see the behavior you are getting when the available RAM does not offer enough addressable space for all requests to "buffer".  Another issue you have is processing power and cores ... although modern phones are getting pretty good they still pail in comparison to standard computing devices.  If you run out of threads the app must wait until one is free.  This can also lead to the issue you are having ... in fact, I bet this is the problem.  I read a forum post before that might help:

[When should we delete the cache data in an iPhone apps?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2626684/when-should-we-delete-the-cache-data-in-an-iphone-apps)

You can clear the cache as follows ... but I am not sure that will solve your issue.  If you are keeping these images around do you intend to store them to the flash memory on the phone?  Remember, if you remove the images from memory then you will need to bring them back up again.  It  may be a better suggestion to reduce the size of the images ... or to load a larger image and sprite across it with DIV's ... if we are talking background images here.  As I am not certain how you have architected the "game" I can not infer the best option.